# How can i use UsageStatsManager in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-android

I try to use [UsageStatsManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.usage.usagestatsmanager) in .NET MAUI.

I asked for permission but I can't get it. It's always denied and of course the *stats* does not return any values.

```cs
private async Task<bool> CheckPermissions()
{
    PermissionStatus status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<PackagePermission.PackageUsageStatsPermission>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            return true;

        if(Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<PackagePermission.PackageUsageStatsPermission>())
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "You must activate manualy", "OK");
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<PackagePermission.PackageUsageStatsPermission>();
    }

    return status == PermissionStatus.Granted;
}
```

And this is my **`BasePlatformPermission`**

```cs
using static Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions;

namespace MauiStats.PackagePermission;

internal class PackageUsageStatsPermission : BasePlatformPermission
{
#if ANDROID
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => 
        new List<(string permission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
            ("android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS", true)
        }.ToArray();
#endif
}
```

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

I would like to get an application like [this](https://ciit.at/android-usagestatsmanager/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official document about the UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) said:

> NOTE: Most methods on this API require the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device still needs to grant permission through the Settings application. See Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS. Methods which only return the information for the calling package do not require this permission

So you also need to let the user grant the permission in the `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` activity:

```
Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionUsageAccessSettings));
```

The will go to the `Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` activity and then the user needs to find the app in the list and grant it the permission.

And then you can use the following code to retrieve applications statistics:

```
var usm = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.UsageStatsService) as Android.App.Usage.UsageStatsManager;
var list = usm.QueryUsageStats(Android.App.Usage.UsageStatsInterval.Daily, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() - 1000*3600*24, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
```

You can check if the permission is granted by checking the count of the list is 0 or the value of the list is null or not.